# I don't understand why my for loop code works

Tags: python, for-loop

I was following a lesson on for loops that told me, as an assignment, using for loops, to print out the even numbers from 1-10, and then print out how many even numbers there are. I was playing around with that and came to this solution:

```
number_even = 0

for i in range(1,10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
        number_even += 1
if i:
     print ('We have', number_even, 'even numbers')
```

I understand everything up until

```
if i:
         print ('We have', number_even, 'even numbers')
```

I honestly was just playing around with Python, but dont understand how I get an expected output from this code. Please help.

Comment: It is unclear to me if you created this solution or if it was provided to you. Regardless `if i` is a shorthand for `if i != 0` but, regardless of your level of skill, this is considered bad practice as it is ambiguous. This comes from how Python interprets non boolean values as `bool`s, but in general you would prefer the second form.

Comment: I found this myself. Something in that introduction video confused me so I went and fiddled with the code. I eventually came to this.

Comment: [VISUALIZE CODE EXECUTION](https://pythontutor.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is generally fine but the last *if* has no sense - you can just delete that condition and leave print statement.
`if some_number` evaluates to True if and only if some_number is 0 (with assumption it's an integer)

But let me share one more version of this task that can help you understand python a bit more:

```
even_numbers = [] # This will be our list of even numbers

for i in range(1,10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_numbers.append(i) # We add number to the list

print(even_numbers) 
print ('We have', len(even_numbers), 'even numbers')
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I am now realizing how pointless that 'if' statement was. Your solution is more clear and makes much, much more sense than mine. Thank you!

Comment: Glad could help and wish you much fun with python! ;)

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your loop, `i=9`, that's why it prints. If you set `i=0` before `if i:` but after the loop, nothing prints.

`if i:` is equivalent to `if i!=0:`

Comment: Thank you!  I just have one question. Why does if I, equal if i != 0?

Comment: @GabrielBurchfield it's just Python syntax. `if i` evaluates if `i is True` which is the same as `i!=0` by default. So it's redundant to write `!=0` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion comes from the confusing nature of Python scopes.

The variable `i` doesn't fall out of scope when your loop ends, like it might in other languages. So, when you reach `if i`, this will succeed because `i == 9`